# asp.net mvc using typeof convert derived type to base type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
   public ActionResult CreateAdminItemsViewModel(int Typeid, int FormId)  
    {
        ViewBag.formid = FormId;


       Type myType1 = Type.GetType("RadioButtonListViewModel");

        BaseViewModel c= myType1; // doesn't work

        return PartialView("CreateAdminItemsViewModel", instantiationType);
    }
```

How can i make this code work? how can i assign my derived type passed from the view to my base view class

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the problem correctly, you need to create an instance of the class `RadioButtonListViewModel` and assign it to a variable of type `BaseViewModel` which is its base class.
To create an isntance of type myType1, you can use

```
var c = Activator.CreateInstance(myType1) as BaseViewModel;
```

Answer (score 1):

With these:

```
Type myType1 = Type.GetType("RadioButtonListViewModel");
BaseViewModel c= myType1; // doesn't work
```

You are getting at runtime a `Type` object and then try to assing it to a `BaseViewModel` refererence: this cleary is wrong.

If you want to assign an instance of `RadioButtonListViewModel`, you can use `Activator`

```
BaseViewModel c = (BaseViewModel)Activator.CreateInstance(myType1);
```

I assume your code is just a semplified version of the real one. If not, you obviusly can use a simple `new`:

```
BaseViewModel c = new RadioButtonListViewModel();
```